# Error when importing CSV to postgres with python and psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I try to COPY a CSV file from a folder to a postgres table using python and psycopg2 and I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 psycopg2.ProgrammingError: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

I also tried to run it through the python environment as:

```
  constr = "dbname='db_name' user='user' host='localhost' password='pass'"
  conn = psycopg2.connect(constr)
  cur = conn.cursor()
  sqlstr = "COPY test_2 FROM '/tmp/tmpJopiUG/downloaded_xls.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
  cur.execute(sqlstr)
```

I still get the above error. I tried \copy command but this works only in psql. What is the alternative in order to be able to execute this through my python script?

**EDITED**

After having a look in the link provided by @Ilja Everilä I tried this:

```
cur.copy_from('/tmp/tmpJopiUG/downloaded_xls.csv', 'test_copy')
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument 1 must have both .read() and .readline() methods
```

How do I give these methods?

Comment: Have a look at http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from or http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert, which seem to employ stdin and stdout, which would allow ordinary DB user to run it.

Comment: Thanks. Please see edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`cursor.copy_expert()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert):

```
constr = "dbname='db_name' user='user' host='localhost' password='pass'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(constr)
cur = conn.cursor()
sqlstr = "COPY test_2 FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV"
with open('/tmp/tmpJopiUG/downloaded_xls.csv') as f:
    cur.copy_expert(sqlstr, f)
conn.commit()
```

You have to open the file *in python* and pass it to psycopg, which then forwards it to postgres' stdin. Since you're using the `CSV` argument to `COPY`, you have to use the expert version in which you pass the COPY statement yourself.

Comment: Oh. That sure wasn't meant to happen. I hope you noticed my edit in between where I fixed the call to `execute()` to `copy_expert()` (had a little copy&paste error there). But still, it really should not segfault.

Comment: Yup. After your edit I don't get the segmentation fault error. But nothing actually happens. No error or warning but still the csv is not uploaded.

Comment: Remember to [`commit()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit).

Comment: Oh man! Thanks so much! Commit DID the trick! I always forget I need to commit the changes.

Comment: I highly recommend [using with-statements with connection objects for transaction handling](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement), and you have to write a lot less boilerplate in the future.

Comment: hello, i have the same problem it not showing anything in the database, but i have commited evertything and closed it after as well. could you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use copy_from. See the code below

```
with open('/tmp/tmpJopiUG/downloaded_xls.csv') as f:
 cur.copy_from(f, table_name,sep=',')
conn.commit()
```