# Python and PG Copy

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the code below which downloads a CSV to memory using sqlalchemy inside of a Django application.

```
engine = create_engine('postgres://.....')

response = requests.get(STOCK_DATA_URL)

zip_file = ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content))
data_file_name = zip_file.namelist()[0]
new_prices = zip_file.open(data_file_name)

df = pd.read_csv(new_prices, names=['ticker', 'name'])
```

Instead of loading it into a dataframe, how would I save it to the database using pg_copy. I tried:

```
connection = engine.connect()
  sql = "copy assets_temp (ticker, name) FROM 'EOD-datasets-codes.csv' DELIMITER ','  CSV;"
  result = connection.execute()
  for row in result:
      print(row)
  connection.close()
```

Error:

```
    ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
 [SQL: "copy assets_temp (ticker, name) FROM 'EOD-datasets-codes.csv' DELIMITER ','  CSV;"]
```

Comment: This should definitely work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37657544/3122880

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use raw_connection with copy_expert command. Change your code to

```
sql = "copy assets_temp (ticker, name) FROM 'EOD-datasets-codes.csv' DELIMITER ','  CSV;"
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.copy_expert(sql)
```

Comment: Yes. That produces the error "required argument 'file' (pos 2) not found"